# connecting my ps4 to my TV

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

When I connect my ps4 to my tv, it reads, connect this device using a USB cable or register it again. even though I used a USB cable to connect my controller to ps4, it doesn't work instead the same information "connect this device using a USB cable, or register it again" keeps appearing. Can someone direct me how to fix this problem.

Comment: Is this a brand new PS4?  One you've used previously and had it work?  One that you bought used and this is the first time you've tried it?  [This page](https://community.playstation.com/content/pdc/us/en_US/pdc-communities/support/Consoles-Peripherals.topic.html/initialised_ps4_cont-KyA1.html) suggests that this may indicate that something is broken.  But it links to this [troubleshooting page](https://support.us.playstation.com/articles/en_US/KC_Article/DualShock-4-Troubleshooting/?) which may help.

Comment: I bought it used already, and it's the first of me using it.

Answer (score -1):

From personal experience .. 
In the process of re-initialising my PS4 I tried re-linking the controller. I had exactly the same problem as the OP. I was using the usb cable originally supplied with the console. Using another usb cable (not a charger only cable which may lack the necessary connections) worked so I can only assume the original cable was faulty.